# Map & filter with observabes

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an observable which return me an array of objects like:

```
0:Object
    id:1
    id_room:1
1:Object
    id:2
    id_room:1
2:Object
    id:3
    id_room:1
```

I'm trying to use find method to find for example only that object who has id = 1, so:

```
getPlaceByPlaceId(placeId: number)  {
 return this.placesService.getPlaces()
   .map( place => place)
   .filter( x => x.id === 1)
   .subscribe(
    x => { 
      console.log(x);
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
    }
   );
```

Method getPlaces from my service:

```
getPlaces(): Observable<Place> {
    return this._http
      .get('./../../assets/api/places.json')
      .map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }
```

.. and places.json:

```
[{
      "id": 1,
      "id_room": 1
  }, {
      "id": 2,
      "id_room": 1
  }, {
      "id": 3,
      "id_room": 1
  }
]
```

Unfortunately I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Console.log not showing any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `filter()` is getting the whole array at once and so trying to filter `array.id` doesn't work because it the array as a whole doesn't have an `id` attribute . You need to `map` the elements out to the `filter` function where you can test each one.

Instead of `.filter( x => x.id === 1)` I think you want:

```
.map(item => item.filter( x => x.id === 1))
```

This should produce a new array with only the items that match `id === 1`.

Comment: hmm, but now I have "Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Place'"

Comment: Wait a minute - you've defined your type as `Observable<Place>` but you aren't returning an Observable of `Places`. You should change your type to reflect an plain array of objects.

Comment: Hmm when I removed this, it changed nothing. I'm new with observables, and probably need more knowledge :/

Comment: The error you are getting is from Typescript, it's complaining because you told it the array from `getPlaces` would contain an `Observable` that resolved to a `Place` object. So when you try to filter the place object it thinks it's a mistake because `Place` objects as far as it knows don't have a `filter()` attribute. You should be able to make it go away by changing the type to something like `Observable<Array<any>>` which reflects what you are really sending from the function.